# C# Drag Drop to desktop, and get the directory

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = new string[] { @"C:\directory\of\file\to\copy.txt" };
    this.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop,files), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

This is the code that i used.

Well, it works well, but want to get the directory of the copied file.
How can I do this?

Comment: The target of the drop may not be something that has a path (dropped into an email message, perhaps?) -- Please explain what you intend to do and maybe there's an alternate solution. For example, if you want to copy additional files into the folder, then you should be doing a multi-file-drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you got is the return value of DoDragDrop() to see if the drop actually happened.  What the receiving app did with the file is something you cannot find out.  Could be anything, including not copying the file at all.  A random example is only opening the file in a text editor, the behavior of VS and Notepad.

Note how the example you gave only drags *from* the desktop, not *to* the desktop.  Use FileBrowserDialog if you need to know where the user wants to copy a file.

Comment: Thank you for answering.. But.. the example i gave in the question does drag to the desktop or explorer when I drag drop on it

Comment: Well, drag it to VS or Notepad instead to see what I'm talking about.  The point is that you cannot find out where it was dragged by the user.  This is entirely be design, D+D avoids getting involved in the implementation details of a program.  Which makes D+D very universal, the program that receives the drop can do anything it wants with the dropped object.  That Windows Explorer uses it to copy a file is an implementation detail that's highly specific to Explorer.  But you can't find out that Explorer got the drop.  So you can't find out where it was copied.

Answer (score 2):

Using that the static **Path** class of **System.IO**,you can extract the path of directory

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Users\JNK\Desktop\2136D.png");
```